# .htacces redirect specific folder/subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying to make this work, please help me in it, if you can:

1.
I have a specific folder on an old domain, with a lot of subfolder.
Looking like this:

OLD-DOMAIN / *FOLDER / something1* etc.

2.
I would like to redirect it to a new domain's specific ABCD folder.

NEW-DOMAIN / **ABCD** / *FOLDER / something1* etc.

I have been using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(FOLDER)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/**ABCD**/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The code is working just fine for the first *FOLDER*, but not for the deeper subfolders. The */something1* doesnt redirecting through the chain.

How can I make this special redirect to every subfolders?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^FOLDER(/.*)?$ http://www.newdomain.com/ABCD/$0 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: This solution just MADE MY DAY! ;-) Thanks!